# .htaccess sitemap rewrite/redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a single domain, multi store setup on magento 2.3

For example

**example.com/jp/

example.com/uk/**

however the sitemaps get generated to their store folders within a sitemaps folder in the root dir, such

**example.com/sitemaps/jp/sitemap.xml**

My google webmaster domains are setup as such

**example.com/jp/**

So when I need to submit a sitemap it needs to be **example.com/jp/sitemap.xml**

I've used

```
#Sitemap: Japan http://www.example.com/sitemaps/jp/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/jp/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]
```

When I access example.com/jp/sitemap.xml its a 404

I'd like **example.com/jp/sitemap.xml** to redirect to **example.com/sitemaps/jp/sitemap.xml**

Is there a way of doing this through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **topmost rule** in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemaps/$0 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure there is no other .htaccess and this rule is top most rule.